# Setting folder to be writable by apache/php in windows?

Tags: apache, writing, save

I have a local test server, and I am attempting to write a file with PHP. I am getting a message that the folder (`../uploads/`) does not exist or I do not have permission.

My directory structure is

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\website\ //<--root
D:\xampp\htdocs\website\library //<--where script runs
D:\xampp\htdocs\website\uploads //<--where I'd like to save
```

I know on a *nix server, I can just chmod the permission to 0777. What do I need to set on my windows box to give apache the ability to write a file?

Comment: pls post some of your code for us to review it. I think the issue must be with the read/write access.

Comment: Are you sure that's the working directory of the script, or is that just the location of the script? If it's a library that is being included from a script in `/htdocs/website/somescript.php`, then the working directory would be `/htdocs/website/`. The working directory can also be changed by the way the script is executed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert on this but as long as the directory is not set to be read only, and it usually isn't by default, it should be writable. Are you 100% sure your path is correct? Have you tried the full path instead of a relative path?

Comment: Best way to find out is to output `getcwd()`. If you use cron to run a php script, or just run it from another directory, then the working directory won't be the script's location.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i don't use XAMPP, but i use WAMP as my test server, it is perfect for my needs since you can enable/disable mods on the run.

If you don't use the Perl install in XAMPP you should maybe check out WAMP at http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Also i read that XAMPP could have problems with file permissions on Windows at 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_on_windows_with_xampp_and_wamp

Comment: That link makes no mention of XAMPP having problems with file permissions on Windows. And I've never had any problems with XAMP not following the file permissions set on the actual filesystem.